# How to add a string at the end of each line accordingly to the name of the file for a list of files?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to append to each line the name of the file.
I guess this can be done either in awk or sed. I tried something like this but it didn't work.

```
for file in *.cds; do  sed -i '/^>/ s/$/[file]/' $file ; done
```

Where I put [file] I want the name of the file between brackets, like [name1].
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You say "each line", but you filter for lines starting with `>` - which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do

```
for file in *.cds; do sed -i 's/$/['"$file"']/' "$file"; done
```

appends file name in square brackets at the end of each line.

**UPDATE:** I don't know why people want to use white spaces in file names  but as commented below, you should quote the bash variables to preserve it as a logical unit for both instances.

If you want to restrict the append only lines starting with `>` add it as a pattern

```
for file in *.cds; do sed -i '/^>/s/$/['"$file"']/' "$file"; done
```

Comment: Breaks for filenames with spaces - `$file` should be quoted both times.

Comment: `'$file'` should be `'"$file"'`

Comment: wrt `I don't know why people want to use white spaces in file names` - no sane person would, but unfortunately there's Windows... :-). Check your own PC and I bet it's littered with file names that contain spaces (as well as files whose content lines end in `\r\n`!).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for inplace editing:

```
awk -i inplace '{print $0 "[" FILENAME "]"}' *.cds
```